# Combine open graph and twitter meta tags?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, social-media, twitter-card

I am adding open graph and twitter meta tags to my site. At first I did this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="${pdict.category.image.absURL}" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="${pdict.category.image.absURL}" />
```

Then I tried consolidating the tags to this:

```
<meta property="og:image" name="twitter:image" content="${pdict.category.image.absURL}" />
```

Twitter had no warnings, FB told me I was missing the og:image property, however it still previewed as I would expect in both. Is there any reason why I should not do this?